# .addClass on initially loaded element

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, viewport

**Situation:**
I have written a function that detects whether `<section>` has entered the viewport via scroll, if so `.addClass('fadeInUp')` else `.removeClass('fadeInUp')` causing the `.animation-element` to fade in on the viewport.

**Problem:** Because the conditional is binded to the scroll function, the 1st `<section>` that is initially loaded does not `.addClass('fadeInUp')` until the user scrolls past then scrolls back to the `<section>`. *[View JS Fiddle for example](https://jsfiddle.net/WeebleWobb/wcw5jpse/9/)*

**Question:** How can I also detect if the initially loaded `<section>` is in the viewport, then `.addClass('fadeInUp')`, etc...

**Current JS function:**

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.animation-element').each(function() {
        if (isScrolledIntoView(this) === true) {
            $(this).addClass('fadeInUp')
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('fadeInUp')
        }
    });
});
```

**Here is the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WeebleWobb/wcw5jpse/9/) of the prototype.**

Comment: Just call the same code you call inside the event handler on the page load...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call the same code you call inside the event hander outside the event handler on the page load.

```
$(function () {

    function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
        var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

        var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

        return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
    }

    function checkElements(selector) {
        $(selector).each(function() {
            if (isScrolledIntoView(this) === true) {
                $(this).addClass('fadeInUp')
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('fadeInUp')
            }
        });
    }

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        checkElements('.animation-element'); // <-- check on scroll
    });

    checkElements('.animation-element'); // <-- check on page load
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what you are asking. Is this what you are looking for?

```
var updateScroll = function() {
  $('.animation-element').each(function() {
    ...
  }
}
$(window).scroll(updateScroll);
updateScroll();
```